# speaker volume always at zero in alsamixer in terminal

Tags: 11.10, sound, alsa

On every startup on Ubuntu 11.10, I have to open terminal and enter `alsamixer` to turn speaker volume up to get sound. Is there a way to lock this in so I don't have to keep opening the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some problem in the interaction of Alsa and PulseAudio. So usually there are two options to work around:

1. *Deinstall PulseAudio*: If you deinstall PulseAudio you will have normal working sound at every startup. However most user find PulseAudio very convenient. So this might not what you want.
2. *Change Audio Settings*: Open gnome-volume-control (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `gnome-volume-control` or System -> Preferences -> Sound). Look at the tab *Hardware* and check if the correct soundcard is configured. Below is a menu called *Profile*. Try different profiles and see if they work. It is hard to say what is the correct option for you. A [forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1395118&page=2) suggested "Analog Surround 5.1", but it depends from your soundcard. If you chosse the correct version, sound settings are the same on each reboot.